# xcodeproj files

Tags: xcode, file

The below files have nothing to do with the project settings, right? It is just properties for the Xcode IDE.

*.mode1v3
*.pbxuser

Answer (score 8):

All `*.mode*`, `*.pbxuser`, and `*.perspective*` files can be safely discarded without affecting project organization. These files are used by Xcode to track which documents are open, which windows are displayed, what their sizes are, and how your project appears.

I ignore everything except for the `project.pbxproj` file when managing projects in version control. Since I use Subversion, I have the following line in ~/.subversion/config:

`global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la .*~ ._* .DS_Store *.pbxuser *.mode* *.perspective*`

Answer (score 2):

Also *.perspectivev3, depending on your version of Xcode.
On the latest, the only important file is "project.pbxproj".

Answer (score 0):

the .pbxuser file does contain custom executables in there. So if you use a custom executable as a unit test runner, (or some other executable) you might have to share that file